# Android Advance Webview Library - Webpage freezes while loading

Tags: android, android-webview

I am loading html5 game from [Advance webview](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView) library. One game is working fine but other game gets stuck after clicking on play button.

I opened the same game on chrome & other browsers (in Android), its working fine there. So the problem is not with the game but with my code.

I have attached the code below. Please check and let me know what is the issue?

**Java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    //getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String url = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.INTENT_URL_KEY);
    isItemPurchased = intent.getBooleanExtra(Constants.INTENT_ITEM_PURCHASED, false);

    AdvancedWebView mWebView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    mWebView.setListener(this, this);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

    mWebView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Comment: Does it show any error in logs

Comment: @IshanFernando no its doesn't